# What is the difference Between gettting location from LocationManager and LocationRequest

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

When ever I search for getting location I got result to get Location via Location Manager but in a tutorial I have seen that they use LocationRequest to get user Location and I have managed to create a Service that give location based on time

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class LocationTrackerService extends Service implements
        GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private LocationClient nLocationClient;
    public static boolean serviceStopCheck = true;
    private DBHelper nDbHelper;
    private int timeForService = 60000;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

//  @Override
//  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
//      timeForService=Integer.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("TIME_FOR_SERVICE"))*1000;
//      return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
//  }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        serviceStopCheck = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        nDbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        nLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
        nLocationClient.connect();
        serviceStopCheck = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        LocationRequest request = LocationRequest.create();
        request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        request.setInterval(timeForService);
        request.setFastestInterval(timeForService);
        nLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(request, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
        if (!serviceStopCheck) {
            LocationItem nLocationItem = new LocationItem(new LatLng(
                    arg0.getLatitude(), arg0.getLongitude()),
                    CommonMethods.getCurentTime(),
                    CommonMethods.getCurentDate());
            try {
                nDbHelper.insertLocationItem(nLocationItem);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            stopSelf();
        }
    }

}
```

So Is better or I have to use LocationManger. Because I think this code is two much easy then using LocationMnager or GPSTracker class provider by some one.

Answer (score 0):

As for me, I have tested that both methods, and I have a conclusion: LocationManager is better, because it uses hardware GPS and it have better accuracy than LocationClient. LocationClient is a part of GooglePlay services, so I think they are using internet coordinates instead of GPS coordinates. But for me the best way is `LocationManager`, cause it was giving me the best accuracy.

Comment: I tried LocationClient without the internet connection but it is still working and giving the Location points. So it not linked with the internet as I suppose. Then what is the differences. Except as I know that LocationClient is depreciated but still it has a new API version. So what is the difference

Comment: Well I checked again you were right about that it get location from internet via Wifi but it get the location via network provider. So the main difference which I found is that it LocationClient does not provide facility to get location from GPS but LocationManager provide all facility of LocationClent plus get location via GPS .

Comment: As I said, LocationManager is more "hardware" :)